# What is the idiomatic Rust way to write this naive JavaScript token scanner code fragment?

Tags: beginner, parsing, rust

I am learning Rust and finding it quite a difficult but rewarding and fun challenge to learn how to write idiomatic and succinct, clean code in it.

I have written the following simple naive JavaScript scanner code as an exercise to learn some basics of Rust.  While it works, it feels like it is far from ideal Rust code.

Are there better ways to write these simple functions?  A few things that stand out to me are:

- The loops and pattern matching feel more verbose than they could be
- The use of the `Chars` iterator feels almost right but somehow off

  - In particular, the `scan_identifier` function is very clumsy since the iterator can't rewind already consumed characters in the string

Note I am a compiler dev and know that this isn't great scanner code.  That is not the point of this exercise.  I am looking to learn how to do Rust basics through practice.

```
fn scan_identifier(first: char, chars: &mut std::str::Chars) {
    let mut identifier = String::new();
    identifier.push(first);

    let mut id_chars = chars.clone();
    while let Some(c) = id_chars.next() {
        match c {
            'a'...'z'|'A'...'Z'|'0'...'9' =>
                identifier.push(c),
            _ => break,
        }
    }
    println!("{}", identifier);
    chars.nth(identifier.chars().count() - 2);
}

fn scan_string(chars: &mut std::str::Chars) {
    let mut string = String::new();
    while let Some(c) = chars.next() {
        match c {
            '\'' => { println!("'{}'", string); return; },
            _ => string.push(c),
        }
    }
    println!("unterminated string! '{}", string);
}

fn scan(src: &str) {
    let mut chars = src.chars();
    while let Some(c) = chars.next() {
        match c {
            '(' => println!("("),
            ')' => println!(")"),
            ';' => println!(";"),
            '\'' => scan_string(&mut chars),
            _ => scan_identifier(c, &mut chars),
        }
    }
}

fn main() {
    let input = "print('Hello, world!');";
    println!("Input:\n\n{}\n\nTokens:\n", input);
    scan(input);
}
```

Comment: *and know that this isn't great scanner code* — it's difficult to provide useful feedback because *we* don't know what *you* already know is "bad". As a made-up example, if we see something wrong but just assume that that's because of "bad" scanner implementation, but you think that's normal Rust, then what should we do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. You should become very familiar with all the methods on `Iterator`; in this case `take_while` would be highly relevant.
2. Other parts of the ecosystem that deal with iterators are invaluable, like `String::extend`.
3. Extract the logic about what is an identifier character, then you can write that code much simpler: `identifier.extend(chars.clone().take_while(is_id_char))`.
4. In most cases, you can use a `for` loop instead of `while let`. `scan_string` is a good example of this. `scan` is **not**, because you wish to pass the iterator into further methods inside the loop body, which is not possible with the `for` syntax.
5. In addition to the standard library Iterator methods, you should internalize what [Itertools](https://github.com/bluss/rust-itertools) provides.
6. For example, `take_while_ref` avoids the need to `clone` the input iterator and then drive the original with `nth`.
7. You could chose to accept a generic iterator instead of `Chars` specifically.

```
extern crate itertools;

use itertools::Itertools;

fn is_id_char(c: &char) -> bool {
    match *c {
        'a'...'z' | 'A'...'Z' | '0'...'9' => true,
        _ => false,
    }
}

fn scan_identifier<I>(first: char, chars: &mut I)
    where I: Iterator<Item = char> + Clone
{
    let mut identifier = String::new();
    identifier.push(first);
    identifier.extend(chars.take_while_ref(is_id_char));

    println!("{}", identifier);
}

fn scan_string<I>(chars: &mut I)
    where I: Iterator<Item = char> + Clone
{
    let string: String = chars.take_while_ref(|&c| c != '\'').collect();

    if Some('\'') != chars.next() {
        println!("unterminated string! '{}", string);
    } else {
        println!("'{}'", string);
    }
}

fn scan(src: &str) {
    let mut chars = src.chars();
    while let Some(c) = chars.next() {
        match c {
            '(' => println!("("),
            ')' => println!(")"),
            ';' => println!(";"),
            '\'' => scan_string(&mut chars),
            _ => scan_identifier(c, &mut chars),
        }
    }
}

fn main() {
    let input = "print('Hello, world!');";
    println!("Input:\n\n{}\n\nTokens:\n", input);
    scan(input);
}
```

---

**I** wouldn't write any parsing / tokenizing / scanning that operates on characters, however. Especially since you are converting from a `&str` to a `String`, when you could just be returning string slices and avoiding extra allocation.

Comment: This is exactly the guidance I needed.  Thank you, @Shepmaster.

Comment: Agreed that slices is the way to go in a real use scenario.